# Need interval to pause when space is pressed again

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code.

```
     <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
              var pressed = 0

            function pullNumber() {
                var x=document.getElementById("number")
        x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+20);
            }
            function beginCountup() {
                var display = document.getElementById("display"),
                i = 0;
                setInterval(function(){display.textContent = ++i; }, 50);

            }
            window.onkeypress = function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                beginCountup();
        }
            }
       </script>
     </head>

     <body>
        <h1>Stop the spacebar at:</h1><h1 id="number">0</h1>
        <button onclick="pullNumber()">Roll new number</button>
        <h1 id="display">0</h1>

     </body>

    </html>
```

CONCEPT:
Press button to roll random number, (rolls number)
and then they player hits (spacebar 32)
the goal is for the player to stop within 5 of the GOAL number
(I might change speed at later date)
the rest i can do. but i cant figure out a way for the spacebar to have a multifunction
that toggles after pressed to another function.

So again space to start, and space to stop

Comment: the function I answered with works fine for me. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vLb5Q/)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `setInterval()` to a variable and stop it there.

```
window.onkeypress = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32){
        clearInterval(window.interval)
    }
}
```

and change `setInterval(function(){display.textContent = i++; }, 50);`
to
`window.interval = setInterval(function(){display.textContent = i++; }, 50);`

Comment: My code is not working ive made an edit to the above post so you can see.

Comment: It's not `++i`, it's `i++`

Comment: What does `textContext` do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearInterval()` function in javascript to clear the Interval which was set earliar.

it takes the IntervalID of `setInterval()` function to clear it.
Example : `clearInterval(IntervalID);`

here you can create two variables:

1.for storing the `IntervalID` : it will be used while calling the `clearInterval()` function.

2.for storing the status of loop : when spacebar is pressed we should stop the loop if loop is running. if loop is not running start it.

the code is as below:

```
  <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
              var intervalID;
              var isCounntRunning=false;
              var pressed = 0


            function pullNumber() {
                var x=document.getElementById("number")
        x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+20);
            }
            function beginCountup() {
                var display = document.getElementById("display"),
                i = 0;
                intervalID=setInterval(function(){display.textContent = ++i; }, 50);

            }
            window.onkeypress = function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                if(!isCounntRunning)
                {
                isCounntRunning=true;
                beginCountup();
                }
                else
                {
                isCounntRunning=false;
                clearInterval(intervalID);
                }
        }
            }
       </script>
     </head>

     <body>
        <h1>Stop the spacebar at:</h1><h1 id="number">0</h1>
        <button onclick="pullNumber()">Roll new number</button>
        <h1 id="display">0</h1>

     </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: @IngoBürk : Thank you sir, now i have edited my answer.please let me know if anything needs to be added.Thanks for your remainder.